# how to write onclick method to call activity from other activity?

Tags: java, android

I am using following code to call my `audio_stream` activity from `MainActivity` by `onClick` method but app crash after clicking on button.

```
radioviewall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent radioInt;
           radioInt = new Intent(view.getContext(), Audio_stream.class);
           startActivity(radioInt);
        }
});
```

Comment: assuming `Audio_stream` `extends Activity` then nothing wrong with your code in here, maybe your bug lies inside `onCreate` of `Audio_stream`? post your code for better answers and also stacktrace of exception

Comment: Can you share exception log?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.api9streamradio, PID: 22879
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.api9streamradio/com.example.pbns.Audio_stream}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3311)

Comment: Please post the code for `Audio_stream.java`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openInsideActivity4();
        }
    });
}
public void openInsideActivity4()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,InsideActivity4.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

intent android open activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(key:,value:);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Source:
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/elixir/how+to+open+another+activity+on+button+click+in+android

Comment: Thank you!. But facing same issue app crash by clicking  in button